# How to use 1 "X" close button to close div element, implemented on multiple divs, closing 1 div per button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have all of these options (rectangles) with a class of ('.caja'), this class is the styling of the rectangle where options are placed and will contain a value to a database.

So, how can I can tell jQuery and CSS to only close one single div element because user will probably dismiss other options along the way? I have tried using the main class element ('.caja') but unfortunately, it makes all div close.

I also have tried naming them with numbers but unfortunately this doesn't seem like a good idea cause it will mean a lot of repetitive code.

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex flex-wrap row justify-content-center">
  <div class="caja caja-1" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Administración de empresas</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Negocios Internacionales</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction2()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction3()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" onclick="myFunction4()">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck5" onclick="myFunction5()">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck6" onclick="myFunction6()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck7" onclick="myFunction7()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck8" onclick="myFunction8()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Administración de empresas</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck9" onclick="myFunction9()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck10" onclick="myFunction10()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck11" onclick="myFunction11()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck12" onclick="myFunction12()">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck13" onclick="myFunction14()">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck14" onclick="myFunction14()">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck15" onclick="myFunction15()">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>

  <div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
    <label class="caja-label">Carrera</label>
    <label class="container-caja">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck16" onclick="myFunction16()">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
  </div>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to actually close 1 div element per close button, preventing closing all boxes when you only want to close one div, and not all of them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For future reference, you'll want to reduce unnecessary verbiage -- I removed paragraphs of irrelevant text from your question -- and when asking for help with javascript please include your javascript code, not just the HTML.

Comment: Hello, Daniel, I have a question regarding my old questions, i want to improve them so i can get my permission back, how can i do this if i don't even have the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to have the function act on DOM elements relative to the one that was actually clicked on.  For example, this code hides the `.caja` element that is the closest parent to the clicked element (`$('this')` in the click handler):

```js
$('.btn-cerrar').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.caja').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
  <label class="caja-label">Item 1</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
</div>

<div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
  <label class="caja-label">Item 2</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
</div>

<div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
  <label class="caja-label">Item 3</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
</div>

<div class="caja" style="background-color: white;">
  <label class="caja-label">Item 4</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
</div>
```